# Port scan results export to CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

How do I export these Python scan results to a CSV file?

```
import socket
import urllib3
import webbrowser
import csv


target = input('[+] Enter Target IP --> ')
print("target = ", target)

startport = input("Enter start port -->")

print("Starting port = ", startport)

endport = input("Enter last port to scan -->")
print("Ending port = ", endport)

print("Running port scan on target: ", target)

for i in range(1, 445):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    conn = s.connect_ex((target, i))
    if (conn == 0):
        print("Port %d:  Open" % (i))
    s.close()

new = 2;
url = "https://www.tenable.com/blog/vulnerabilities-by-common-ports-dashboard"

for i in range(1, 445):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    conn = s.connect_ex((target, i))
    if (conn == 0):
        webbrowser.open("https://www.tenable.com/blog/vulnerabilities-by-common-ports-dashboard", new=2)
        print("Opening website vulnerabilities by common ports")
    s.close()
```

Comment: What have you tried to export it?

Comment: This is all I have tried so far.  I've been doing a ton of research but can't seem to find a simple solution:  with open('Results.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

Comment: Are you sure a reader is the right choice for exporting?

Comment: No, I am not sure.  This is my first attempt at an export using python.  Am coming at this wrong?

Comment: what all you want to export! All the `print` statements?

Comment: My goal is to write the data (scan results) to a CSV then read it.

Comment: @Koolaidninja that's what I asked, what all needs to be wriiten to the CSV? All the `print` statements?

Comment: Yes Sir, I would like to write the print statements.

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you storing all the open ports in csv file. All you need to do is add this code exactly in the "if" part of the code

```
fields=['i']
 with open(r'name.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
```